# Git config : Can I use different pagers for different commands?

Tags: git, less, pager

I am happy with Git bash as is, and with `less` as a pager.

But I want to see line numbers only in some cases (option `-N` to `less` in the case of `show` or other commands that will show file contents), and otherwise use the same other options to `less` in all cases.

Is this possible in a simple way ?

Comment: Can you explicit the cases you mention? There might be solutions.

Comment: `git help config` indicates it is possible, though for some reason I can't get it working. Setting `core.pager.show` to `less -N` should work.

Comment: [`git config --global pager.show "less -N"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt).

Comment: @phd @chepner That's the one thank you. I thought individual pager options could only be `true` or `false` to specify wether this commands uses the core pager or not.